# \uppercase command does not work with greek characters

Tags: fonts, greek, capitalization

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\uppercase{\textgreek{τα κεφαλαία δεν δουλεύουν}}

\selectlanguage{greek}
\uppercase{τα κεφαλαία δεν δουλεύουν}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: uppercase doesnt work]

As it can be seen the `\uppercase` command doesn't seem to work with greek characters, or it seems to work partly.

Comment: With a recent (less than two years) TeX distribution, loading `LGR` is not necessary.

Comment: @egreg So only `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is needed, or is that unnecessary too?

Comment: That's not required too, if the language with Latin alphabet you use is English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `\MakeUppercase` instead of `\uppercase`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\uppercase{\textgreek{τα κεφαλαία δεν δουλεύουν}}

\selectlanguage{greek}
\uppercase{τα κεφαλαία δεν δουλεύουν}

\MakeUppercase{τα κεφαλαία δεν δουλεύουν}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\MakeUppercase` works! But, why doesn't `\uppercase` work?

Comment: @egreg: Done already before you commented ;-)

Comment: @svart: `\MakeUppercase` expands its argument: `τ` etc. are actually no characters but macros here, `\uppercase` alone will not extract the full information of those macros and look for the relevant upper case version.

Answer (score 4):

To complement Christian’s answer, let me recall what `\uppercase` does.

When you do `\uppercase{<text>}`, the *characters* in `<text>` (as opposed to commands) are converted to their uppercase equivalent as established by a vector loaded into memory.

For example, `a` will turn into `A`, because the vector contains, at the slot `0x61` the value `0x41`; on the other hand commas and so on will not change, because in the corresponding slots the vector has 0 (which is the marker telling TeX not to change the character).

Now, for LaTeX, a tau is not a single character, but two (due to UTF-8), precisely the characters in slots `0xCF` and `0x84` (hexadecimal).

Here is the correspondence table when LaTeX starts up:

```
80->80    81->81    82->82    83->83    84->84    85->85    86->86    87->87
88->88    89->89    8A->8A    8B->8B    8C->8C    8D->8D    8E->8E    8F->8F

90->90    91->91    92->92    93->93    94->94    95->95    96->96    97->97
98->98    99->99    9A->9A    9B->9B    9C->9C    9D->9D    9E->D0    9F->0

A0->80    A1->81    A2->82    A3->83    A4->84    A5->85    A6->86    A7->87
A8->88    A9->89    AA->8A    AB->8B    AC->8C    AD->8D    AE->8E    AF->8F

B0->90    B1->91    B2->92    B3->93    B4->94    B5->95    B6->96    B7->97
B8->98    B9->99    BA->9A    BB->9B    BC->9C    BD->0     BE->0     BF->0

C0->C0    C1->C1    C2->C2    C3->C3    C4->C4    C5->C5    C6->C6    C7->C7
C8->C8    C9->C9    CA->CA    CB->CB    CC->CC    CD->CD    CE->CE    CF->CF

D0->D0    D1->D1    D2->D2    D3->D3    D4->D4    D5->D5    D6->D6    D7->D7
D8->D8    D9->D9    DA->DA    DB->DB    DC->DC    DD->DD    DE->DE    DF->DF

E0->C0    E1->C1    E2->C2    E3->C3    E4->C4    E5->C5    E6->C6    E7->C7
E8->C8    E9->C9    EA->CA    EB->CB    EC->CC    ED->CD    EE->CE    EF->CF

F0->D0    F1->D1    F2->D2    F3->D3    F4->D4    F5->D5    F6->D6    F7->D7
F8->D8    F9->D9    FA->DA    FB->DB    FC->DC    FD->DD    FE->DE    FF->DF
```

(just the characters beyond `0x7F` are shown here). There are reasons behind these values, but it would take too long to explain them.

Anyway, you see that `0xCF` and `0x84` don't change, so a tau will remain unchanged. On the other hand a kappa is input as `0xCE` and `0xBA`; the first part doesn't change, the second one becomes `0x9A` and the combination `0xCE` followed by `0x9A` in UTF-8 is indeed an uppercase Greek kappa.

There's no way this can work for every UTF-8 character; moreover, control sequences would remain the same, which would be a nuisance for other languages (for instance, in German `\ss` should become `\SS`, for proper output).

Thus LaTeX has introduced `\MakeUppercase` that “does the right thing”, using `\uppercase` in some cases, a different conversion table in others.

Similarly, `\lowercase` should not be used in LaTeX: the correct command is `\MakeLowercase`.